# Chrome JavaScript calculate line-height, position different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a simple text reader it has a line for easy-reading.

It uses keyboard arrow up and down key each excutes adjust the 'top' position of the red-line based on line-height property. Here is the function.

```
var line = example.$line[0],
    $text = example.$text,
    top = parseFloat(line.style.top).toFixed(1) / 1,
    lineHeight = parseFloat($text.css('line-height')).toFixed(1) / 1; 

// UP KEY PRESSED
if (move == 'up') {
    line.style.top = (top - lineHeight) + 'px';
    return;
}
// DOWN KEY PRESSED
if (move == 'down') {
    line.style.top = (top + lineHeight) + 'px';
}
```

But, only the Chrome seems different results.
How can i fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/laires/f93t1ado/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: yes, but working in IE11 only native code. not fiddle. in Chrome, move lines more down then appears different position about 0.x pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `line-height` also in `px` will fix the issue.

[**See this working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f93t1ado/1/) (I just tested on Chrome).

I have only changed your css from this:

```
line-height: 1.8;
```

To that:

```
line-height: 22px;
```

Comment: thanks solved this way. have some problems with related font-size toggle.. but solved just wrote all font-size <-> line-height css classes.